# How can I add a displacement modifier to part of this object?

Tags: modifiers

[image][image][image][image]I successfully added a woodgrain displacement modifier to this object but I do not want woodgrain in the holes or on the bottom of the object. What would be my best approach going about doing that? This will be for 3D printing so I need the actual deformation.

Comment: The _Displacement_ modifier has the option to only affect a vertex group.

Comment: Thank you, that seems to get me closer (I added a couple more images to show what I selected and the result). I am not sure why I am getting grain in the holes still and not so much on the horizontal flat faces based on the vertices I selected???

Comment: It seems I may not be understanding how I add a vertex group. I tried selecting a rectangle of vertices but I don't see how it gets added to become part of a vertex group?  I added another image to show where I am at.

Comment: Okay, got it. I had to create the group first.

Comment: Different displacement depth by planes can be caused by non uniform scale issues. Try to apply scale (Ctrl+A >Scale)

Comment: Thanks, right now I am struggling with trying to create a vertex group now that I have increased the number of vertices a bunch by subdividing. Selection is very slow and I am crashing the program after selecting so many.